# JQUI datepicker invisible dates bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

**[DEMO OF ISSUE](http://jsfiddle.net/USD38/)**

I've just ran into an issue with the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) where there are clickable *invisible* elements at the end of a month.

Using a pretty basic set up like so;

```
$('#start_date').datepicker({
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
    minDate: 1,
    maxDate: '+1y'
});
```

I'm able to click in the area highlighted yellow in the screenshot and it then acts like a click on a valid date and errors out with the date output;

[image: example]

It doesn't happen on the jqui datepicker website, however I'm not really doing anything fancy with this one so can't understand why it might break like this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('#start_date').datepicker({
   selectOtherMonths: false,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
   minDate: 1,
   maxDate: '+1y'
});
```

Comment: Just figured it out myself. The issue was that I had `selectOtherMonths` set to true, but by default `showOtherMonths` is set to false, therefore there were elements to click that weren't being shown. As I do want other months selectable I just needed to add `showOtherMonths: true`